# HTML Form Submission in golang template

Tags: html, forms, go, go-templates

I am using the go language to submit an HTML form using the go-template. Getting some weird results.

The basic idea is that I have a data structure called Page containing a few elements. The template is populated with an array of Pages. Inside the template I iterate through each Page and display its contents. Each of these contents are embedded inside an HTML form with its respective link. Once the link is clicked it will submit the respective form.

The code snippet is as follows:

```
{{range $index, $element := .Pages}}                                                                            
  <form action="/detailNews" id="readMore{{$index}}" method="post" name="readMore{{$index}}">
    //displaying elements from each page                    

    <div id="more">
      <input name="query" type="hidden" value="{{printf "%s" .Title}}">                         
      <a href="#" onclick="document.readMore{{$index}}.submit()">Read More</a>
    </div>

  </form>
{{end}}
```

The code mostly works with one little problem. The id and the name attributes generate outputs as expected such as: **readMore0**, **readMore1**, etc.

The problem is at the "a" tag where the onclick attribute is populated with this: **document.readMore 0 .submit()**, **document.readMore 1 .submit()**, etc. Note the **space** surrounding 0, 1. With this, the respective form is not being found when the link is clicked.

I can't figure out the reason of this.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Ripul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have a working example to reproduce? I tried locally and it works as expected:

http://play.golang.org/p/ZnM0RqIMfL

```
package main

import (
        "os"
        "text/template"
)

type Page struct {
        Title string
}

func main() {
        template.Must(template.New("test").Parse(`
{{range $index, $element := .Pages}}
  <form action="/detailNews" id="readMore{{$index}}" method="post" name="readMore{{$index}}">
    //displaying elements from each page

    <div id="more">
      <input name="query" type="hidden" value="{{printf "%s" .Title}}">
      <a href="#" onclick="document.readMore{{$index}}.submit()">Read More</a>
    </div>

  </form>
{{end}}
`)).Execute(os.Stdout, struct{ Pages []Page }{Pages: []Page{
                {Title: "page1"}, {Title: "page2"},
        }})
}
```

Result:

```
 <form action="/detailNews" id="readMore0" method="post" name="readMore0">
    //displaying elements from each page

    <div id="more">
      <input name="query" type="hidden" value="page1">
      <a href="#" onclick="document.readMore0.submit()">Read More</a>
    </div>

  </form>

  <form action="/detailNews" id="readMore1" method="post" name="readMore1">
    //displaying elements from each page

    <div id="more">
      <input name="query" type="hidden" value="page2">
      <a href="#" onclick="document.readMore1.submit()">Read More</a>
    </div>

  </form>
```

Comment: The difference between your and mine was that I used the html/template and you used the text/template package. I changed it to text/template and it seems to work! I need to understand the difference between the template of the html and the text package. Many thanks for that.

Answer (score 6):

This is happening because of [escaping contexts](http://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#pkg-overview).

> By default, this package assumes that all pipelines produce a plain
>   text string. It adds escaping pipeline stages necessary to correctly
>   and safely embed that plain text string in the appropriate context.
>
> When a data value is not plain text, you can make sure it is not
>   over-escaped by marking it with its type.
>
> Types HTML, JS, URL, and others from content.go can carry safe content
>   that is exempted from escaping.

In order to overcome it you should pass the page index as part of the `.Pages` element structs typed as [`template.JS`](http://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#JS). Something like this :

```
type Page struct {
         Id    template.JS
         Title string
}
```

Comment: Hi Emil, many thanks for your reply. Let me try this. However, I have one question. Why is this only being affected in the onclick attribute? For example, just for experiment, when I have moved `document.readMore{{$index}}.submit()` to href attribute, it produces the correct output. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: @Ripul It is context aware so it detects where you are placing the variable HTML, JS, etc. and "adds escaping pipeline stages necessary to correctly and safely embed that plain text string". So the escaping differs for the different contexts.